# Is there a difference between Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).toString()) and list.get(i) if list is an arraylist<Double>

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists of doubles created like this:

```java
ArrayList <Double> axis_x = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList <Double> axis_y = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Now, I have seen a difference in the calculations when I use (because I wanted to simplify the calculations)

```java
for(int j=0; j<axis_x.size();j++) {
    double ax_x = Double.parseDouble(axis_x.get(j).toString()) + Math.abs(left_scale);
    axis_x.set(j,ax_x);//axis_y.get(i);
    double ax_y=0.0f;
    if(Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString()) < 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString())) + Math.abs(up_scale);
    }else if(Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString()) > 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString()) - Math.abs(up_scale));
    }else if(Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString()) == 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(up_scale);
    }
    axis_y.set(j,ax_y);
}
```

VS

```
for(int j=0; j<axis_x.size();j++) {
    double ax_x = axis_x.get(j) + Math.abs(left_scale);
    axis_x.set(j,ax_x);
    double ax_y=0.0f;
    if(axis_y.get(j) < 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(axis_y.get(j)) + Math.abs(up_scale);
    }else if(axis_y.get(j) > 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(axis_y.get(j)) - Math.abs(up_scale);
    }else if(axis_y.get(j) == 0.0f) {
        ax_y = Math.abs(up_scale);
    }
    axis_y.set(j,ax_y);
}
```

Knowing that `axis_y.get(i)` should be a double, is `Double.parseDouble(axis_y.get(j).toString())` not the same as `axis_y.get(i)`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: In one, you're getting the original value of the double, in the other you're converting it to a string and then converting it back to a double.  This should be fine for numbers with relatively low precision, but if there's high precision you're going to run the risk of getting some floating point errors.  For floating point numbers, you should avoid type conversion if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see the two mentioned ways of getting the `Double` item:

```java
final ArrayList<Double> axis_x = new ArrayList<Double>();

// Way #1. Getting the Double item from the `List<Double>`
//   without performing any conversions.
final int i = 0;
final Double x = axis_x.get(i);

// Way #2. Getting the Double item from the `List<Double>`
//   with performing two redundant conversions.
final Double x =
    // `String => Double` conversion.
    Double.parseDouble(
        // `Double => String` conversion.
        axis_x.get(i).toString()
    );
```

The way #1 **should be used** to get the item directly, i.e. without performing any conversions.

The way #2 uses two redundant conversions: `Double => String` and `String => Double`.
Therefore, this way should be avoided.

Comment: The way 2's redundancy was the reason why I wanted to switch to way 1, but I got completely other values in the end.. annoying.

Answer (score 1):

#1: `final Double x = axis_x.get(i);`

Double <= Double

#2: `final Double x = parseDouble(axis_x.get(i).toString());`

Double <= String <= Double conversion.

way 2 is not the smart and shorter way.
also the way 1 is the exact value.

Comment: Thanks. This is probably why I have not the exact same values.